# success message from php to android when data saved in mysql database

Tags: php, android

I'm going to create a simple register form app that when user insert their username and password, that should be stored in database and get a success message on the screen.in my app data is stored but how to show success message in toast

```
public class Register extends Activity {
    EditText fname;
    EditText lname;
    EditText uname;
    EditText passw;
    EditText contact;// To take birthyear as input from user
    Button submit;
    Button cancel;
    TextView tv;      // TextView to show the result of MySQL query

    String returnString;   // to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
                .penaltyLog().build());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.efname);
        lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elname);
        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reuname);
        passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repass);
        contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        // tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);

        // define the action when user clicks on submit button
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(contact.length()<10)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Please Enter correct mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(passw.length()<6)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Please Enter minimum 6 letters in password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the name "birthyear" and its value submitted by user
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                // define the parameter
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname",
                        fname.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname",
                        lname.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                        uname.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                        passw.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact",
                        contact.getText().toString()));
                String response = null;

                // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                            "http://192.168.2.17/pro/insert1.php", // your ip address if using localhost server
                            // "http://omega.uta.edu/~kmr2464/jsonscript.php",  // in case of a remote server
                            postParameters);

                    // store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
                    String result = response.toString();



                    //parse json data
                    /* try{
                         JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                         String aJsonString = jObject.getString("$my");
                         if(aJsonString.equals("1") )
                         {
                             Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             return;
                         }
                    //  returnString = "";
                    // JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    // for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    //JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                    //  ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                    // ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                    // ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                    //  );
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    //returnString += "\n" + json_data.getString("name") + " -> "+ json_data.getInt("birthyear");
                    //   }
                    }
                     catch(JSONException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
                     }*/

                    try{
                        tv.setText(returnString);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. What is your *exact* question?

Comment: you cannot use this inside oncreate directly for this you need an assynctask like background thread

Comment: Well he can use this in onClick as posted as he invoked StrictMode. But it is bad practice and OP should indeed use an AsyncTask.

Comment: Have you never used a Toast? Please indicate where you wantt to use a Toast. As you have it now you can use it every where.